# .NET Create Icon Overlay(the same behavior as Dropbox and google drive ) using Sharpshell along with FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher, sharpshell

I want to create Icon overlay in my synchronization app (i want the same behavior as Dropbox and google drive); i already watched the local changes using FileSystemWatcher but i can't add icon overlay according to file status;
I read this article but i can't find anything related to my scenario:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545781/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Icon-Overlay-Handlers
I want to change icons based on file status

Answer (score 0):

Amount of Overlay icons is limited in Windows. You have 15 available slots at all.
And if you have already installed Dropbox + Google Drive + OneDrive (prebuilt in windows) > you have no free slots anymore ;)

Read here for more info >
https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell/issues/93